# How to rotate bounding box in open CV and crop it (python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have the coordinates of a rectangle (XMIN,YMIN,XMAX & YMAX) on a particular image. I wish to rotate the rectangle at a particular angle and then  crop it from the image. 
How do I do that??

For example this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRBtm.png).i have got the output bounding box appearing on the left side (plotted it using XMIN,YMIN,XMAX & YMAX). I want to rotate it as per the image on the right side and then crop it.

Can someone provide the way to get this output with a sample code or point me to a link with the explanation

Comment: Please make your question clearer. Are you asking to plot the 4 points on what background? Some image? Or just the coordinates? Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: done...hope now it is clear

Comment: Crop your image to those bounding box coordinates. Use cv2.rotate() see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d99/classcv_1_1Affine3.html#a990d571a479b9b336f30c259fb74d18c. The get the contour and its rotated bounding box. See cv2.minAreaRect() https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9. Alternately, rotate the image. Compute the rotated box coordinates, draw a filled polygon from the rotate points. Use the filled polygon as a mask to blank out the background. Post your original input image without extra lines drawn on it.

Comment: What angle to you want to rotate it? What are the exact bounding coordinates? Please write full requirements when you ask questions and provide your original images, not composites or screen snaps.

Comment: Here's a nice discussion of the various options: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV
- Do color thresholding on the green box
- Get the outer contour
- Print the bounding box
- Rotate the image by 10 deg clocwise
- Convert that image to HSV
- Do color thresholding on the rotated green box
- Get the outer contour
- Create a black image with the white filled contour
- Get the white pixel coordinates
- Get the minAreaRect from the coordinates
- Get the vertices of the rotated rectangle
- Draw the rotated rectangle outline on the rotated image

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

# load image
img = cv2.imread("berry.png")

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold using inRange or green
range1 = (20,200,170)
range2 = (80,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv,range1,range2)

# get bounding box coordinates from the one outer contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
print("bounding_box(x,y,w,h):",x,y,w,h)

# rotate image by 10 degree clockwise
rotated = img.copy()
rotated = ndimage.rotate(img, -10, cval=255)


# convert rotated to hsv
hsv_rotated = cv2.cvtColor(rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold using inRange or green
range1 = (20,200,170)
range2 = (80,255,255)
thresh_rotated = cv2.inRange(hsv_rotated,range1,range2)

# get bounding box coordinates from the one outer contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_rotated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# draw white filled contour on black background
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh_rotated)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [contours[0]], -1, (255), -1)

# get coordinates of white pixels in mask
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(mask.transpose() > 0))

# get rotated rectangle
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)

# rotated rectangle box points
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rotrect))
print("rotate_box_corners:\n",box)

# draw rotated rectangle on rotated image
result = rotated.copy()
cv2.polylines(result, [box], True, (0,0,255), 1)


# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("berry_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("berry_rotated.png", rotated)
cv2.imwrite("berry_thresh_rotated.png", thresh_rotated)
cv2.imwrite("berry_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("berry_rotated_box.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("ROTATED", rotated)
cv2.imshow("THRESH_ROT", thresh_rotated)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold of green lines in input:

[image]

Rotated input:

[image]

Threshold of green lines in rotated image:

[image]

Filled threshold:

[image]

Result showing rotated rectangle on rotated image:

[image]

Input Bounding Box:

```
bounding_box(x,y,w,h): 12 13 212 124
```

Output Vertices:

```
rotate_box_corners:
 [[222 172]
 [ 14 136]
 [ 35  14]
 [243  51]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a rotation matrix to rotate both the images and the bounding boxes.

Steps:

1. Generate a rotation matrix
2. Use OpenCV `warpAffine` to rotate the
   image
3. Rotate the 4 corners of the bounding box using the same
   rotation matrix

Read about [getRotationMatrix2D](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326) and [warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983)

```
    img_path = '' #The image path
    bb = [] #XMIN,YMIN,XMAX,YMAX
    angle = 3 #Rotation angle in degrees, +ve is counter-clockwise
    
    bb = np.array(((bb[0],bb[1]),(bb[2],bb[1]),(bb[2],bb[3]),(bb[0],bb[3]))) #Get all 4 coordinates of the box
    
    img = cv2.imread(img_path) #Read the img
    
    center = (img.shape[0]//2,img.shape[1]//2) #Get the center of the image
    
    rotMat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0) #Get the rotation matrix, its of shape 2x3
    
    img_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img,rotMat,img.shape[1::-1]) #Rotate the image
    
    bb_rotated = np.vstack((bb.T,np.array((1,1,1,1)))) #Convert the array to [x,y,1] format to dot it with the rotMat
    bb_rotated = np.dot(rotMat,bb_rotated).T #Perform Dot product and get back the points in shape of (4,2)
    
    #Plot the original image and bb
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.plot(
        np.append(bb[:,0],bb[0,0]),
        np.append(bb[:,1],bb[0,1])
    )
    plt.show()
    
    #Plot the rotated image and bb
    plt.imshow(img_rotated)
    plt.plot(
        np.append(bb_rotated[:,0],bb_rotated[0,0]),
        np.append(bb_rotated[:,1],bb_rotated[0,1])
    )
    plt.show()
```